# Python class inheritance __init__

Tags: python, class

So, here's the problem..

if you do this:

```
class x(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
```

why would you explicitly call **init** in child class to access parent class attribute? (class y has class x attribute anyway.)

```
class y(x):
  def __init__(self):
    x.__init__(self)
```

Cheers.

Edit:

I read this article https://linuxmeerkat.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/why-you-should-use-super-in-python/, it says "In real life we tend to run the initializer for every parent class. This is simply **because of how program designs tend to be**. In our simple example a way to solve this is to explicitly call the initializer of A:" Could someone please explain?

Comment: The base class might change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that in python there is a clear distinction between class and instance attributes:

- Attributes declared in the class body, outside any method, are **class attributes**, they are the same for each object of that class and are the ones that are inherited by the subclasses. Be aware of the fact that doing `instance_obj.class_att = something` doesn't change the value of the class attribute, but simply creates an instance attribute and hides the shared class attribute for that object.
- **Instance attributes** are the ones that are declared with syntax `instance_obj.att = something`, they are not shared between instances and are the most similar thing to non-static attributes that you have in other programming languages and they are usually created in the **init** method.`self` is just a convention to indicate the instance object automatically passed to methods.

Here's an example:

```
class MyClass:
    c = 1                    #class attribute, the subclasses will inherit this
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 1           #instance attribute

MyClass.c     #access attribute c of class MyClass
MyClass.i     #error! MyClass has no attribute i
x = MyClass() #calling __init__ creates instance attribute i for obj x
x.i           #access instance attribute i of object x
x.c           #access class attribute c of class MyClass
x.c = 2       #hide MyClass.c and create instance attribute c for obj x
x.c           #access instance attribute c of obj x
```

So, to sum up, doing:

```
class y(x):
    def __init__(self):
        x.__init__(self)
```

is useful because if the base class would have been something like this

```
class x:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i=1
```

you would have not been able to access the attribute i from any instances of y simply because they would not have it.

Comment: Thanks but if base class attr changed, like in your example `self.i=1`, calling x.__init__(self) in `class y` will get the attribute `i` for `class y` , wouldn't it?

Comment: @Roy i is an instance attribute, but sure, that's the reason why you do that!

Comment: Soz, how's `i` an instance attribute, if it's defined in `class x` already??

Comment: @Roy I've edited my answer adding another example, I hope it helps. I suggest you to find a good reference and study OOP in python in detail to have a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: If `__init__` doesn't do anything *except* call `x.__init__`, you don't need to define it at all; `y` will just inherit `x.__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the child class inherits from the parent class, of course, that means everything: methods, attributes and the constructor.
So instead of rewrite all the `__init__` code, you just use what is already written in the parent class.
Hope it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling to the **init** function explicitly,  you should use the super() method instead.

*In python 3.0+, you can jusy use:*

```
class y(x):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

*In python 2.7 or under, use:*

```
class y(x):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
```

**super() lets you avoid referring to the base class explicitly.**